# Is it legal to use previous function parameter to declare new one?

Tags: c++, function, gcc, language-lawyer

The following code compiles cleanly with GCC:

```
void func(int arg1, decltype(arg1) arg2)
{
    (void)arg2;
}
int main(){}
```

I used this command to compile:

```
g++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -o test -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra
```

But such usage of a parameter in the middle of function declaration seems weird. Is it actually valid in standard C++, or is it a GCC extension?

Comment: I assume that the type of `arg1` is much more complex in your actual code? And without looking at the specification or any references, but knowing some about parsing, I would guess it's okay, because parsing languages like C++ is very much a top-to-bottom left-to-right affair. When the compiler parses the declaration for `arg2` it must have already parsed the declaration of `arg1` so it definitely know the type of `arg1`. If it's really "allowed" I don't know, neither if it will work in the opposite direction (using `decltype(arg2)` for `arg1`).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg of course, actual code has much more complex type for `arg1`, otherwise I would even think of trying to use `decltype` on it.

Comment: FWIW, MSVC++2013 and its Intellisense (EDG) both accept it as well.

Comment: The preferred way to match parameter arguments is through a template parameter (though that is not what the question is asking), though I think what you are proposing is valid.

Comment: @callyalater But it's not a function template. OP wants a specific type for `arg1`, and that same type for `arg2` (just that that type is apparently a PITA to spell)

Comment: @Barry I know. That is why I specified in my comment ("that is not what the question is asking"). I was offering an additional approach to the problem.

Comment: This is more that just permitted, there are times when this might be the desired behaviour. e.g. `void func(T &arg1, decltype(std::begin(arg1)) beginIt, decltype(std::end(arg1)) endIt)` (There's probably a better example, but that's the best I could think of).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is fine. The `ISO C++11 Standard` even gives your situation as an example.

First the parameter is in scope:

**3.3.3** Block scope **[** basic.scope.local **]**

> **2** The potential scope of a function parameter name (including one appearing in a lambda-declarator) or of
>   a function-local predefined variable in a function definition (8.4) begins at its point of declaration.

An example can be found here:

> **8.3.5** Functions **[** dcl.fct **]**
>
> **5** ***[*** Note: This transformation does not affect the types of the parameters. For example, int(*)(const int p, decltype(p)*) and int(*)(int, const int*) are identical types. — end note **]**

Comment: @AaronHall The `C++11` Standaard is sold here: http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2FISO%2FIEC+14882-2012 but you can get a free draft (near identical?) by googling for "n3290.pdf". All drafts up to (but not including) the final are free.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it's legal. It's basically just a question of scope. From [basic.scope.block]:

> The potential scope of a function parameter name (including one appearing in a *lambda-declarator*) or of a function-local predefined variable in a function definition (8.4) begins at its point of declaration.

The scope of `arg1` begins here:

```
void func(int arg1, decltype(arg1) arg2)
------------------^
```

Hence `arg1` is in scope for the declaration of `arg2`. I think that's sufficient.

The rule for disallowing defaulting `arg2` to `arg1` is separate -- which to me suggests that `arg1` was in scope and had to be explicitly disallowed.

Answer (score 6):

If we look in N3979 [dcl.fct.default] we have

> Default arguments are evaluated each time the function is called. The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. Consequently, parameters of a function shall not be used in a default argument, even if they are not evaluated. **Parameters of a function declared before a default argument are in scope and can hide namespace and class member names**. [ Example:
>
> ```
> int a;
> int f(int a, int b = a);              // error: parameter a
>                                       // used as default argument
> typedef int I;
> int g(float I, int b = I(2));         // error: parameter I found
> int h(int a, int b = sizeof(a));      // error, parameter a used
>                                       // in default argument
> ```
>
> [...]

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

So in the example `a` is known when we get to `b` and it hides the `a` from the calling scope.  This leads me to believe each function parameter is known before each subsequent parameter.  This means you should be able to use its type.  You cannot use its value - as the order of evaluation of the values is unspecified - but the names should be introduced in order from left to right.

Comment: They're definitely in scope, but is that sufficient?

Comment: @MSalters to use them with `decltype` I think so.